# How to use values in another dataframe to apply limits to every element in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset in a data frame. Below is the output of the current dataframe I have:

```
>>df1


   index       0        1      2        3      4        5      6        7      8        9  ...     1002     1003     1004     1005     1006     1007     1008     1009     1010     1011     1012
0  row0   94.864   94.074  1.977   94.461  1.963   90.549  2.005   98.240  1.957   90.464  ...   94.596   93.296   99.390   96.931   96.297   98.340   91.753  100.984   94.885   92.277  107.398
1  row1  110.008  100.368  2.275  112.876  2.307  107.358  2.243  103.077  2.286  101.782  ...  110.381  107.835  109.564  106.138  102.641  131.907  114.220  107.475  107.969  101.017  103.152
2  row2  110.008  100.368  2.275  112.876  2.307  107.358  2.243  103.077  2.286  101.782  ...  110.381  107.835  109.564  106.138  102.641  131.907  114.220  107.475  107.969  101.017  107.461
3  row3   88.840   92.313  1.859   94.001  1.844   85.570  1.883   92.241  1.838   86.022  ...   89.304   92.369   88.552   88.054   90.898   89.741   91.640   98.408   92.920   91.954   99.651
4  row4   93.423   90.212  2.077   93.603  2.126   95.304  2.039   91.824  2.088   92.385  ...   92.460   91.089   89.120   94.700   90.886   91.239   93.875   90.737   90.568   89.140   95.270
```

I have a different dataframe with the "limits" of each row. Below is that dataframe:

```
>>df2


     LL          UL
0   1.0        2.20
1   1.0        2.60
2   1.0        2.60
3   1.0        2.03
4   1.0        2.45
```

Basically what I want is to figure out which cells fall within the corresponding limits and which cells do not
For example, the first row would look something like this where 1 means it falls within the limits and 0 falls out of the limits(based on the limits in row0 of df2):

```
0  row0   0   0  1   0  1   0  1   0  1   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0   0   0  0
```

These values don't have to be 0 and 1, they could also be boolean values.

I tried to do this by using this `df.apply(calcs, args=(df2))` where calcs is:

```
def calcs(val, df2):
    if (val > df2["LL"].iloc[val.name]) and (val < df2["UL"].iloc[val.name]):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Is there a fast way to do this? I am working with huge datasets and I don't want to take too long to compute.

**Edit:**
Just to clarify: The limits in each row in df2 correspond to the limits of just that row in df1. For example, the limits in row4 in df2 have to be applied to the values in row4 of df1

Comment: Do you want the df2 limits to apply to every row or just have row 1 be the limits for row 1 in df1?

Comment: The limits in each row in df2 correspond to the limits of just that row in df1. For example, the limits in row4 in df2 have to be applied to the values in row4 of df1

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize the comparision. I used only part of your example data.

```
df1.set_index('index', inplace=True)
df2.set_index(df1.index, inplace=True)

(df1.gt(df2.LL, axis=0) & df1.lt(df2.UL, axis=0)).astype('int').reset_index()
```

Out:

```
  index  0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  row0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1
1  row1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1
2  row2  0  0  1  0  1  0  1
3  row3  0  0  1  0  1  0  1
4  row4  0  0  1  0  1  0  1
```

Setup for the smaller example

```
import pandas as pd
import io

t = '''
   index       0        1      2        3      4        5      6
0  row0   94.864   94.074  1.977   94.461  1.963   90.549  2.005
1  row1  110.008  100.368  2.275  112.876  2.307  107.358  2.243
2  row2  110.008  100.368  2.275  112.876  2.307  107.358  2.243
3  row3   88.840   92.313  1.859   94.001  1.844   85.570  1.883
4  row4   93.423   90.212  2.077   93.603  2.126   95.304  2.039'''
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+')
df1
```

Out:

```
  index        0        1      2        3      4        5      6
0  row0   94.864   94.074  1.977   94.461  1.963   90.549  2.005
1  row1  110.008  100.368  2.275  112.876  2.307  107.358  2.243
2  row2  110.008  100.368  2.275  112.876  2.307  107.358  2.243
3  row3   88.840   92.313  1.859   94.001  1.844   85.570  1.883
4  row4   93.423   90.212  2.077   93.603  2.126   95.304  2.039
```

```
t1 = '''
     LL          UL
0   1.0        2.20
1   1.0        2.60
2   1.0        2.60
3   1.0        2.03
4   1.0        2.45'''
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t1), sep='\s+')
df2
```

Out:

```
    LL    UL
0  1.0  2.20
1  1.0  2.60
2  1.0  2.60
3  1.0  2.03
4  1.0  2.45
```